# Renaming objects with Wing IDE

Tags: python, eclipse, ide

I am just transitioning from Eclipse to Wing IDE for my Python code. In Eclipse I had an option to "rename" objects. I could take any object defined in my code, it could be a variable or a function or a method or whatever, and I could rename it automatically in all the files that referenced it.

Is there a similar feature in Wing IDE?

Comment: No, AFAIK, No. I use WingIDE everyday, and I love thie IDE. It is still NO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WingIDE 4 now has support for refactoring.

Answer (score 4):

The refactoruing is a feature asked for [since 2002](http://wingware.com/pipermail/wingide-users/2002-May/001102.html), but even then, the answer was already:

"[search and replace](http://www.wingware.com/doc/intro/tutorial-search)"

> BTW, one somewhat related thing we're doing is adding better global
>   replace. `[...]` This isn't informed by source analysis but it's still a useful tool for some kinds of refactoring (like renaming poorly named variables or classes).

So their advanced search, even based on regex, is still the refactoring of the day for this 3.1.8 Wing IDE: as [said in 2007](http://wingware.com/pipermail/wingide-users/2007-July/004506.html), the 3.0, 3.1 releases were focused on debugging even though:

> Refactoring is in our plans for future releases.

(but not yet for the [upcoming 3.2](http://wingware.com/wingide/beta), it seems: see here the [full CHANGELOG](http://wingware.com/pub/wingide/prerelease/3.2.0-b3/CHANGELOG.txt))

[image]
<sub>(source: [wingware.com](http://www.wingware.com/images/doc/en/intro/search-regex.png))</sub>